# SharedPreferences in a game

Tags: java, android

Hello StackOverflow Community, I have a problem with my sharedPrefs and I dont get it (im a beginner) I want to make a simple game but i stuck at the HiScore.It allways displays O. Those are some code snippets.

```
 MainActivity:
 SharedPreferences prefs;
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 prefs = getSharedPreferences("HiScores", MODE_PRIVATE);
 long longestDistance = prefs.getLong("longestDistance", 1000000);

 GameActivity:
 private SharedPreferences prefs;
 private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
 prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("HiScores", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 editor = prefs.edit();
 longestDistance = prefs.getLong("longestDistance", 1000000);

 private void update() {
 if(distanceTaken < longestDistance) {
 editor.putLong("longestDistance", distanceTaken);
 editor.commit();
 longestDistance = distanceTaken;
 }
 if(distanceTaken >= 100000) {
 distanceTaken = 100000;
 gameEnded = true;
 }
 private void startGame(){
 distanceTaken = 0;
 }
```

Thank you for the help :)
Niclas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `if` statement to judge longest distance is wrong,I think you want is the distance now longer that longest ever,then save it,but you mistaken this:

```
 if(distanceTaken < longestDistance) {
     editor.putLong("longestDistance", distanceTaken);
     editor.commit();
     longestDistance = distanceTaken;
 }
```

should be:

```
 if(distanceTaken > longestDistance) {
     editor.putLong("longestDistance", distanceTaken);
     editor.commit();
     longestDistance = distanceTaken;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) I will mark ur answer if its possible (5min)^^